# Fill NA in a list with the last know value in Python

Tags: python

I am looking a way to fill na in a list with the last known value in python.

Example: `Input a = [1, 2, None, 4, 5, None, 5, 4, None, 7, None, None, None, None]`

```
Output: [1, 2, 2, 4, 5, 5, 5, 4, 4, 7, 7, 7, 7,7]
```

If the first element is None then we have to replace this with first non null element in the list and then do the above task.

Comment: What should be expected result if 1st element would be None?

Comment: If the first element is None then we have to replace this with first non null element in the list and then do the above task.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply use [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate) and [`next`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#next).

```
a = [1, 2, None, 4, 5, None, 5, 4, None, 7, None, None, None, None]
b = [None, 2, None, 4, 5, None, 5, 4, None, 7, None, None, None, None]
c = [None, None, None, 4, 5, None, 5, 4, None, 7, None, None, None, None]


def fill_none(a):
    for i, j in enumerate(a):
        if j is None:
            if i == 0:
                a[0] = next(item for item in a if item is not None)
            else:
                a[i] = a[i-1]
    return a


>>> print fill_none(a)
[1, 2, 2, 4, 5, 5, 5, 4, 4, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7]
>>> print fill_none(b)
[2, 2, 2, 4, 5, 5, 5, 4, 4, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7]
>>> print fill_none(c)
[4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 4, 4, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
lis = [1, 2, None, 4, 5, None, 5, 4, None, 7, None, None, None, None]
for x in range(len(lis)):
    if lis[0] == None:
        lis[0] = 1
    if lis[x] == None:
        lis[x] = lis[x - 1]
print(lis)
```

Output = [1, 2, 2, 4, 5, 5, 5, 4, 4, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7]